# “Invalid array length” error when updating tree structure with new data in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, tree

I'm encountering a problem with my tree data structure in TypeScript. When I execute the `updateInputArray(chatTree);` function, I receive an “invalid array length” error at the line `totalArray.push(iteratorNode.data);`. Additionally, the browser freezes when I attempt to log within the `returnStringArray()` function, suggesting a potential infinite loop.

The tree appears to be structured correctly initially, as verified by a printTree function. However, the issue arises when the tree is traversed via priority nodes.

Tree creating function:

```
  async function addChatData() {
    if (Params && chatId) {
      try {
        const messages = (await fetchChatData({
          userId: 'not important',
          chatId: chatId,
          getAll: false,
        })) as string[];
        //console.log(messages);
        let i: number = 0;
        let k: number = 0;
        const temp: TreeNode[] = [];
        for (const message of messages) {
          i = 0;
          try {
            const versions = (await fetchChatData({
              userId: 'not important',
              chatId: 'not important',
              messageId: message,
              getAll: false,
            })) as string[];
            const messageNode = new TreeNode(' ', message);
            chatTree.children.push(messageNode);

            for (const version of versions) {
              try {
                const versionOfMessage = (await fetchChatData({
                  userId: 'not important',
                  chatId: 'not important',
                  messageId: 'not important',
                  versionOfMessageId: version,
                  getAll: true,
                })) as VersionOfMessage;
                //console.log('Version data: ', versionOfMessage);
                const data: string = versionOfMessage.content;
                const newNode = new TreeNode(data, message);
                // Add the new node as a child to the message node
                messageNode.addChild(newNode);

                if (i === 0) temp.push(newNode); //store priority child of node

                i++;
              } catch (error) {
                console.error(
                  'Could not get version of message object ',
                  error,
                );
              }
            }
            //messageNode.priorityChild = 0;
            if (k > 0) {
              //add message node to previous child to let all priority children be accessed via the returnStringArray fcn.
              temp[k - 1].addChild(chatTree.children[k]); 
              //temp[k - 1].priorityChild = 0;
              //console.log(temp);
            }
            k++;
          } catch (error) {
            console.error('Could not get version list: ', error);
          }
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Could not get message list: ', error);
      }
    }
    updateInputArray(chatTree);
    //console.log(chatTree.printTree());
  }
```

main function of updateInputArray function:

```
  returnStringArray(): string[] {
    let iteratorNode: TreeNode = this.children[this.priorityChild];
    const totalArray: string[] = [];

    while (iteratorNode) {
      // If the node's data is not just a space, add it to the totalArray (i.e., skip messageNode data).
      //console.log(iteratorNode);
      if (iteratorNode.data.trim() !== '') {
        totalArray.push(iteratorNode.data);
      }
      // Proceed to the priority child if it exists, or break the loop
      if (iteratorNode.children.length > 0) {
        iteratorNode = iteratorNode.children[iteratorNode.priorityChild];
      } else {
        break; // No more children, so we break the loop
      }
    }

    return totalArray;
  }
```

I am completely stumped on what the issue is, so any help or future debugging steps would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: My recommendation here is rather than console logging, use a debugger. If you're in a browser (which it sounds like you are), you can open your code in the source tab and click the sidebar on the left of the line to set a debug breakpoint. The code then will stop at that point allowing you to see what the variables are. Might be a little complex because it'll be transpiled typescript, but you should be able to figure it out. I suspect something is off with iteratorNode.data, and it sounds like you have the same suspicion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have messages without versions, then your code will create cycles in your "tree":

Imagine a minimal example to produce a cycle:

- Let's have just two messages, let's call them A and B.
- A has no versions, B has one version

After the first iteration of the outer loop, `chatTree` has one child, i.e. node "A", and `temp` is empty (because there are no "versions"). `k` is set to 1.

In the second iteration of the outer loop, just after the inner loop has finished, `chatTree` has two children (one for "A", one for "B"), and `temp` has the first (and only) "version" node for "B".

As now `k` is greater than zero, the following link is made:

From the node in `temp` (a child of "B") to ... node "B"!! This creates a cycle.

And so your `returnStringArray` will get into an "infinite" loop and after 32K iterations, the array `totalArray` has reached the maximum length possible, leading to the error you got.

Conclusion: the logic of interlinking nodes is wrong. You'll have to revamp that. Without knowing the rest of your code, I can only sketch what could be a solution. I'd suggest dropping the variables `i`, `k` and `temp`, and instead use `prevChild`, like so:

```
    let prevChild = null; // TreeNode
    for (const message of messages) {
        // ...
        const messageNode = new TreeNode(' ', message);
        // ...
        for (const version of versions) {
            //...
        }
        if (messageNode.children.length) {
            if (prevChild) {
                prevChild.addChild(messageNode); // This sets the link
            }
            prevChild = messageNode.children[0];
        }
    }
```